# Compilar C++ usando o Gradle

Tags: c++, gradle

O **Gradle** e um grande aliado no desenvolvimento java e android. Eu estava olhando no site e percebi que ele também pode gerenciar projetos em c++.

Como eu posso usa-lo para compilar um projeto super simples (hello word)?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html

Comment: [Em inglês.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059516/c-with-gradle)

Comment: Rodrigo, esses links resolveram a dúvida? Se sim, por gentileza poste uma resposta explicando! Obrigado.

Comment: No endereço abaixo, disponivel no github, você encontrará vários exemplos de configurações disponíveis para o Android NDK e Gradle. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk Inclusive você encontrará vários exemplos de "Hello"

Comment: Resolveram ou não?

Comment: nao ... mas eu ainda gostaria de ver a resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// build.gradle
apply plugin: 'cpp'

libraries {
   hello {}
}
executables {
   main {
      binaries.all {
          lib libraries.hello.shared
      }
  }
}
```

- Este exemplo disponibilizado [aqui](http://carlosvin.github.io/en/posts/gradle-cpp.html)
- caso queira aprender mais sobre gradle [esse curso](https://br.udacity.com/course/gradle-for-android-and-java--ud867/) é bem completo e free